# MySQL select where not already selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort through some data that I am pulling from my database and I realized that the most efficient way would be to do it directly in the SQL query rather than in PHP or javascript. I have a database with the following schema:

```
Table_1
position | company | etc.
  CEO    |   ABC   |
  CEO    |   CBA   |
  CEO    |   CBA   |
 Intern  |   XYZ   |
  CFO    |   MNO   |
  CFO    |   MNO   |
  CFO    |   MNO   |
```

I am currently just pulling all that data, converting it to JSON and sending it to the browser and letting the browser do all the organization, etc. but the much more efficient way to do it would be to only select the rows that haven't been selected before. So instead of loading all the data like above, it would only load this from the database:

```
Table_1
position | company | etc.
  CEO    |   ABC   |
  CEO    |   CBA   |
 Intern  |   XYZ   |
  CFO    |   MNO   |
```

I need the query to not select a row when both the position and company are the same as a previously selected row. And this is where I keep getting stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, I am selecting multiple columns from the database (Eg. year_start, year_end, linkedID, link) which can all have different values even if `position` and `company` are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `DISTINCT` to get only unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT position, company
FROM tableName
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  position, company, MAX(year_start) year_start
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY position, company
        ) b ON  a.position = b.position AND 
                a.company = b.company AND
                a.year_start = b.year_start
```

if you have an auto_incremented column, better use that rather than `year_start`.

Comment: followup question: are the values the same for all columns assuming you want to select all column in a row in both rows? otherwise `DISTINCT` will not work on that case. can you be more specific? `:)`

Comment: based on the updated question, which one of the records do you want to get since they could have different values on the other columns?

Comment: I would like to select the record that has a higher `year_start` value (It's a 4 long integer).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` should work fine for the purpose of this exercise, there is no need for inner joins on the same table with a MAX().

If you want the maximum value from a column you can definitely use

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.bla,
                MAX(A.bla2) as bla2
FROM table
GROUP BY A.bla
```

without the joins.